# Simple Return Statements PHP

Tags: php, assert

I have the following function and assertions.

```
function howReturnDis($str) {

    if (strlen($str) < 4) {
        echo "Returning 0";
        return 0;
    }
    echo "Returning 1";
    return 1;
}

assert ( 0, howReturnDis("") );
assert ( 0, howReturnDis("aba") );
assert ( 1, howReturnDis("ABBA a b b a") );
assert ( 2, howReturnDis("abbabba") );
```

The first two assertions fail. The second two assertions pass. 
**Please explain why!** I would have thought that last assertion should fail and the others should pass (Clearly I'm wrong, but I don't get it). Thanks in advance.

Comment: `assert()` takes an expression or boolean. It does not compare its first and second parameter.

Comment: To expand on @mario's comment, you just need to rewrite your statements a little: `assert(howReturnDis("") == 0)`

Comment: Bingo. Thanks, all!